# How to import a python script which uses matlab engine without compiling it

Tags: python, matlab

I am writing a python program that uses Tkinter for UI. I have to separate python files: interface.py and script.py. The script.py contains a code which calls a matlab script using matlab.engine module. The interface.py contains UI elements should call script.py when I press a certain button i.e. after I press a button in my program it runs matlab.scripts specified in script.py. However when I run interface.py, even though I just import script.py without actually calling its functions, it still starts matlab.engine on the program startup, as I understand it compiles and interpetes script.py when I import it. What I need is that matlab.engine written inside a function in script.py will be called when I want it to and not during the program startup.

Here is script.py:

```
import matlab.engine

def implement():

  eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
  eng.matlab_script(nargout=0)
  eng.quit()
```

Here is interface.py snippet containing the function and the button:

```
def analyze():
        import script
        script.implement()
        
analyzeButton = Button(self, text = "Analyze ->", bg='#0D0628', width=10, height=2, command = analyze())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute this line of code:

```py
analyzeButton = Button(self, text = "Analyze ->", bg='#0D0628', 
                       width=10, height=2, command = analyze())
```

you are actually running the `analyze` function, which will start the MATLAB engine and run your MATLAB script.

In Python, `analyze` is a reference to a function, and `analyze()` calls the function. You want to set `command=analyze`, not `command=analyze()`. The former will pass the function reference to the button constructor, the latter will run the function and pass the function's return value to the button constructor.